# Proving that $\sqrt{\frac{2n-1}{n+1}}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I show that $\sqrt{\frac{2n-1}{n+1}}$ is convergent?

I know that $\frac{2n-1}{n+1}$ is convergent, so how can I use that to show that the square-root of it is convergent too

Comment: Do you know about continuity?

Comment: [This](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Continuity.aspx) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say I use comparison test where $$u_n=\sqrt{\frac{2n-1}{n+1}}$$ and $$v_n=1$$

Now $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{2n-1}{n+1}}$$
$$= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{2-\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}} = \sqrt{2}$$ and this limit = $\sqrt{2}$ is finite. 
Since $v_n=1$ is a constant sequence and hence convergent sequence, by comparison test(special form), we can say that $u_n$ is convergent.

Comment: You really should explain why $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{ \dfrac{2 - \frac{1}{n}}{1 + \frac{1}{n}}} = \sqrt{2}$.  It's not as simple as saying "by continuity" because continuity tells us for any real number $a$, $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$, but $\infty$ is not a real number.  So why can you put the limit on the inside of the square root?

Comment: @user46944 I thought that it's elementary. Anyways if I consider $u=\frac{1}{n}$ then as $n\to\infty \,\ u\to 0$ and 0 is a real number. So I can use $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$. Is it okay now?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.  For a student that needs help with this type of problem, it's not elementary and should be mentioned.